# Why can I access the event object inside of my callback function with explicitly accepting it as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm playing around with JavaScript event listeners and I found that I can access the event object inside the callback function I provide to the event listener, even without specifically setting it as a parameter. Why does this work? I can't find any information about it.

I have tried this in a few different browsers, wondering if it was an strange implementation of the `addEventListener` function, but it worked in all of them. I have also tried providing different functions as a callback, including inline function expressions, function declarations and arrow functions, and they all worked as well.

Here is an example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div>Click Me!</div>

    <script>
      const div = document.querySelector('div');

      function test() {
        console.log(event);
      }

      div.addEventListener('click', test);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I expect that event should be undefined, but it's not. I can't figure out why.

Comment: because some browser have `window.event` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event

Comment: `event` is a global. It's a holdover from (of all things) how IE did it - assigning the *current* `event` to `window` for...simplicity, presumably.

Comment: That makes perfect sense now. Thanks!